# Is climate a small-scale or large-scale process?

Tags: scale, terminology

This might sound like a stupid question but it bothers me anyway:

We distinguish small-scale maps like world-maps and large-scale maps like a map of my local neighborhood. So far, so clear.

However, when we talk about geographic processes like climate, it feels counter-intutive to consider climate as a small-scale process since it affects the weather on a global scale and the earth is large.

So, what is the correct term: Is climate (or any other process which operates on a global scale) a small-scale or large-scale process? What terminology is to be preferred in science and the general public?

Comment: There does not appear to be a GIS component to your question which I think would be better asked at the [earthscience.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

While the same words are used, they have a different meaning in these situations. The [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/large-scale) tells us:

> **large-scale**
>
> 1. adjective [ADJECTIVE noun] A large-scale action or event happens over a very wide area or involves a lot of people or things. ...a
>      large scale military operation. Synonyms: wide-ranging, global,
>      sweeping, broad   More Synonyms of large-scale
> 2. adjective [ADJECTIVE noun] A large-scale map or diagram represents a small area of land or a building or machine on a scale that is large
>      enough for small details to be shown. ...a large-scale map of the
>      county.

So for a map, the scale is the ratio between a distance on paper and a ground distance *(1:10,000* is a larger scale than *1:100,000*) while for a process the scale is rather a representation of the impacted ground area (*the seism was felt 50 km away* is a smaller scale effect than *the hurricane was perceived 1,000 km away*)

That being said, so many people use the wrong definition for a map scale (i.e. only looking at the denumerator and not at the ratio), that you could tactfully define what you mean (*... in this small scale map - so having a large denumerator - we can see that ...*)